# pgfplots: Plot multiple xbar in same plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to make a two bar plots together just like below, but with an xbar instead.

[image]

However, this is proving to be harder than required for me. Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\linewidth,compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}% table
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            bar width=0.7,
            xlabel=Quantidade de vendedores/consumidores,
            ylabel=Estado,
            ytick=data,
            yticklabels from table={data/num_sellers_per_state.dat}{State},
            enlargelimits=0.05,
            legend pos=south east,
        ]
            
            % Customer data
            \addplot table[
                y expr=\coordindex,
                x=CustomerSize,
            ] {data/num_sellers_per_state.dat};
            
            % Seller data
            \addplot table[
                y expr=\coordindex,
                x=SellerSize,
            ] {data/num_sellers_per_state.dat};
            
            \legend{Consumidores,Vendedores}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

and here are the contents of the `data/num_sellers_per_state.dat` file:

```
State   CustomerSize    SellerSize
RR  46  0
AP  68  0
AC  81  1
AM  148 1
RO  253 2
TO  280 0
SE  350 2
AL  413 0
RN  485 5
PI  495 1
PB  536 6
MS  715 5
MA  747 1
MT  907 4
PA  975 1
CE  1336    13
PE  1652    9
GO  2020    40
ES  2033    23
DF  2140    30
BA  3380    19
SC  3637    190
PR  5045    349
RS  5466    129
MG  11635   244
RJ  12852   171
SP  41746   1849
```

What I end up receiving is a plot with the bars on top of each other, as shown below.

[image]

I tried setting `bar width` and `bar shift` properties, but nothing works. I looked for multiple questions relative to this but they all seem to work for ybars only.

Edit: Fix typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You actually only need to increase the height of your plot or decrease the width of the bars (or better yet, both):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{num_sellers_per_state.dat}
State   CustomerSize    SellerSize
RR  46  0
AP  68  0
AC  81  1
AM  148 1
RO  253 2
TO  280 0
SE  350 2
AL  413 0
RN  485 5
PI  495 1
PB  536 6
MS  715 5
MA  747 1
MT  907 4
PA  975 1
CE  1336    13
PE  1652    9
GO  2020    40
ES  2033    23
DF  2140    30
BA  3380    19
SC  3637    190
PR  5045    349
RS  5466    129
MG  11635   244
RJ  12852   171
SP  41746   1849
\end{filecontents}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% table
    \begin{axis}[
        height=15cm,
        xbar,
        bar width=.15cm,
        xlabel=Quantidade de vendedores/consumidores,
        ylabel=Estado,
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels from table={num_sellers_per_state.dat}{State},
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        legend pos=south east,
    ]
        
        % Customer data
        \addplot table[
            y expr=\coordindex,
            x=CustomerSize,
        ] {num_sellers_per_state.dat};
        
        % Seller data
        \addplot table[
            y expr=\coordindex,
            x=SellerSize,
        ] {num_sellers_per_state.dat};
        
        \legend{Consumidores,Vendedores}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

(Note, I changed the path to the file in the code in order to make it work with `filecontents`.)

[image]

Comment: Well, that was silly of me :). I started incorrectly using `xbar interval` with the same values and it worked with no overlap; but of course, other stuff were breaking because, well, I was using it incorrectly. So increasing the image height never crossed my mind!

Thanks for the quick answer and for the welcome!